# HtmlEncode from Class Library

Tags: c#, html-encode

I have a class library (in C#). I need to encode my data using the HtmlEncode method. This is easy to do from a web application. My question is, how do I use this method from a class library that is being called from a console application?

Comment: Related post - [HtmlEncode in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1631819/465053)

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Import System.Web
Or call the System.Web.HttpUtility which contains it

You will need to add the reference to the DLL if it isn't there already

```
string TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
string EncodedString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(TestString);
```

Comment: You need to create an instance of the Server Utility class which is designed to support a current in progress Request and emulate features the old ASP Server object.  HttpUtility is a lighter weight set of Static methods.

Comment: Make sure that your framework type does not specify "Client Profile".  Changes this to the full framework and you'll have the system.web assembly available

Comment: System.Web.HttpUtility was not available in my project (.NET Framework 4.7.1). System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) was available and worked fine.

Answer (score 215):

[`System.Net.WebUtility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility) class is
available starting from .NET Framework 4.0 — you donʼt need System.Web dependency.

Comment: Thanks, Now I can use the .NET 4 Client Profile instead of the full framework!

Answer (score 41):

If you are using C#3 a good tip is to create an extension method to make this even simpler. Just create a static method (preferably in a static class) like so:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string HtmlEncode(this string s)
    {
        return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s);
    }
}
```

You can then do neat stuff like this:

```
string encoded = "<div>I need encoding</div>".HtmlEncode();
```

Answer (score 29):

Try this

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string);
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string);
```

Comment: This is much better because I don't have to add reference to System.Web in my WPF project.

Answer (score 7):

Add a reference to System.Web.dll and then you can use the System.Web.HtmlUtility class

Answer (score 3):

Just reference the System.Web assembly and then call:
HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In case you're using SharePoint 2010, using the following line of code will avoid having to reference the whole System.Web library:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(stringToEncode);
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are working with silverlight, use this:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(...);
```