# Convert HTML codes to plain text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

I've a string for example like this:

```
Col&acute;gio
```

How can I convert it to:

```
Colégio
```

Without having to do a replace for all the html codes

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144535/c-sharp-htmlencode-from-class-library or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122641/how-can-i-decode-html-characters-in-c. There are also plenty of other instances of this - you need to Html DECODE the string.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Col&acute;gio");
```

Answer (score 9):

Just for completion:

If you are using .NET 4.0+ you can also use WebUtility.HtmlDecode

Answer (score 2):

```
SecurityElement securityElement = System.Security.SecurityElement.FromString("<test>H&amp;M</test>");
string unescapedText = securityElement.Text;
Console.WriteLine(unescapedText); // Result: H&M
```