# Converting unicode not working in c#

Tags: c#, unicode

I am trying to convert unicode character in c# but it is not working

code:

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace test_request
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            string unicode = "Not Your Boyfriend&#39;s Tunic";
            string str = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(unicode);


            Console.WriteLine (str);
        }
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
Not Your Boyfriend&#39;s Tunic
```

But expected output is this

Expected output:

```
Not Your Boyfriend's Tunic
```

Comment: That isn't unicode? That's HTML encoding.

Comment: may be it works :`string unicode = EncodeNonAsciiCharacters(unicodeString);`

Comment: str = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(unicode);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML codes to plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735502/convert-html-codes-to-plain-text)

Comment: @AmolRaje What is `EncodeNonAsciiCharacters`? What namespace and class does it live in? Is it a method you have implmented in your own project, by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace test_request
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            string unicode = "Not Your Boyfriend&#39;s Tunic";
            string str = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(unicode);
            Console.WriteLine (str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below function:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Not Your Boyfriend&#39;s Tunic");
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Not Your Boyfriend's Tunic");
```

Answer (score 2):

Both solutions will work for you:

1. Using **Server.HtmlDecode**:

   ```
    string unicode = "Not Your Boyfriend&#39;s Tunic";
    string str = Server.HtmlDecode(unicode);
    Console.WriteLine (str);
   ```

   reference link: [This MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. Using **HttpUtility.HtmlDecode**:
   hello

   ```
   string unicode = "Not Your Boyfriend&#39;s Tunic";    
   string str = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(unicode);
   Console.WriteLine (str);
   ```

   reference link: [This MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Difference between both:

Both does same work but the only difference is: Server.HtmlDecode() is readily availalble at runtime from a web page whereas HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() is a static method that can be used from anywhere.