# Fully encoding a url

Tags: c#, urlencode, url-encoding

I have run into a problem when encoding a URL. I understand the differences between `UrlPathEncode` and `UrlEncode`, but I seem to have run into an instance where neither will help.

I want to encode the following `my-page-???-testing`. When using `UrlPathEncode` it ignores anything after the first `?`, and `UrlEncode` escapes all spaces into `+`, which is not what I want.

Is there a method I could use to encode question marks too?

Comment: What is the problem with encoding spaces into `+`. This is the standard way to encode urls so saying that you don't want to do this is likely to result in it just being custom code (eg find and replace type things). Also if you don't want the space to + then you might want to edit your title since you don't want full encoding. ;-)

Comment: As `?` is integral to traditional querystring name/value pairs, I'm not sure it's a valid target character for encoding. It may well be a "roll-your-own" solution.

Comment: did you try HtmlEncode...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144535/c-sharp-htmlencode-from-class-library

Comment: Chris, encoding space into `+` is only valid in the query string portion of the url. All other spaces must be encoded into `%20`.