# How to save HTML Tags and its attributes in sql table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using textarea. This Textarea functionality is similar to Rich Text Box. My textarea has

```
<div style="width:100px;"><div style="height="400px;"></div></div>
```

In button click event I want to save this text in database table.
But my coding saved like this

```
<div><div></div></div>
```

Comment: you have to use htmlencode class before saving to db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you have to encode your code

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    string a = WebUtility.HtmlEncode("<html><head><title>T</title></head></html>");
    string b = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a);

    Console.WriteLine("After HtmlEncode: " + a);
    Console.WriteLine("After HtmlDecode: " + b);
    }
}
```

output

After HtmlEncode:

```
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;T&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
```

further read these articles

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144535/htmlencode-from-class-library
```

and

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx
```

and

```
http://www.dotnetperls.com/htmlencode-htmldecode
```

Comment: I am using html decoding only.But inside the div tag i am using style attribute inside div tag style="width:100px;".That one was not saving into database table.

Comment: <div style="width:100px;"><div style="height="400px;"></div></div> after html decoding i am getting like this <div><div></div></div>

Comment: flag a breakpoint and debug then let me know second use tinymice or ajaxhtml editor dont use textarea