# Remove html tags from string, and keep text openxml friendly?

Tags: c#, html, .net, ms-word, openxml

I am inserting text into an open XML document. The text I retrieve and insert into the document contains HTML formatting, i.e < p >some text< / p > < p >More text< / p > thus the inserted text inside word gets this as text. Can text with HTML get cast to something open XML documents will understand ?

Answer (score 1):

**New answer:**

There is actually a project on codeplex that does exactly what you are looking for.

See here the project here:
[Html to OpenXml on codeplex](https://html2openxml.codeplex.com/)

However; if the formatting (headings/paragraphs etc...) are not important you can just strip the HTML-tags entirely.

Here is a tutorial on how to do that:
[C# Remove HTML Tags](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags)

---

**Old answer *(OP worded his question a bit odd, and i misunderstood)*:**

What you need to do is encode your HTML-code somehow; you could use base64 or whatever floats your boat. "Simple" HTML-encoding would probably be the best course of action here.

This way the HTML will not break your XML.

ASP.NET has support for this; but you can do it in any application by importing the required namespace.

Here's an example.
[HtmlEncode from Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144535/htmlencode-from-class-library)

Comment: Hi.

I get this result &lt;p&gt;some textt. &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt; 
This wasn't very XML friendly :) .
I used this class:
string TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
string EncodedString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(TestString);

Comment: Yes. That can safely be stored in your XML and then be decoded when you need it. :)

Comment: I need to decoded it right away :),  I developed  a button, and on button click an open XML (ms word) document is generated. I create a document using memory stream and write text to on the fly. The strings that I write to the generated document have html formatting. I have tried to remove the formatting by using HthmlEncode class as suggested and tried to strip the html. If i strip the html, the tags are removed, and then I loose the space between paragraphs. If I use HthmlEncode I get special characters in the document. All I want is to have some formatting open XML (Word) can understand.

Comment: Ah, I think i have misunderstood you, and you have misunderstood XML. I will update my answer accordingly.